# How do I make my C# application self-aware?

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence

How can I make my C# applications self-aware?

e.g. able to read and write its own code and decide whether or not to bother to execute your commands.

Kindest Regards

Comment: This is a feature that MSFT will add in C# version 107.  By then Eric Lippert will be fully cybernetic.

Comment: Will make sure I "Got on with real life"!

Comment: Ask Sarah Connor if this is a good idea.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=are+you+skynet

Comment: @jamietre: What exactly did you mean by that last comment? That as a Windows user, you find the Mac OS difficult to navigate? I thought so. (In the future, please keep the noise comments likely to incite a flame war to yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple libraries to check out.

http://code.google.com/p/aforge

http://www.heatonresearch.com/download

http://prolog.hodroj.net

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure about what you're asking but you might want to look into [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).